# How to prevent creation of spaces when italicizing part of a 2 lines axis label

Tags: r

In the R boxplot below, on the x axis, I am trying to write labels on 2 lines, with the name of the treatment on the first line and the sample size on the second line, where N (and N only) must be italicized. When I italicize "N", a space appears after the name of the treatment (here after "Control" and "-25%"),  and between "(" and "N" on the second lines. (I didn't italicize N in the last 4 treatments so you can see what the labels should look like). Using:

```
pup.mass.M <- data.frame(diet1, diet2, diet3, diet4, diet5, diet6)

boxplot(pup.mass.M, font=c(3), main="Males pupal mass", cex.axis=1, xlab="Diet casein content", xaxt='n' , yaxt='n', ylab="Mass (g)", ylim = c(0.22, 0.38), las = 1)

axis(side = 2, at=seq(0.22, 0.38, by=0.02), las = 1, mgp = c(3,1,0))

axis(side = 1, at=seq(1, 6), labels = c(expression(paste("Control\n(", italic("N"), " = 29)")), expression(paste("-25%\n(", italic("N"), " = 21)")), "-50%\n(N = 13)", "-75%\n(N = 18)", "-90%\n(N = 23)", "-99.7%\n(N = 19)"), mgp = c(3,1.5,0))
```

Boxplot with labels partly italicized:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal and reproducible example. Please don't forget we don't have access to your data.

Comment: @HubertL  Please refrain using slang language and please provide arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that making the `N` italic is taking up more space than is available.  So R has to find a way to squeeze everything into your x axis labels and ends up wrapping the text and creating weird spaces.  To fix this, try using the `cex.axis` parameter in your to `axis()` when you create your x axis labels:

```
axis(side = 1,
     cex.axis=1,    # adjust this value until everything fits
     at=seq(1, 6),
     labels = c(expression(paste("Control\n(", italic("N"), " = 29)")), expression(paste("-25%\n(", italic("N"), " = 21)")), "-50%\n(N = 13)", "-75%\n(N = 18)", "-90%\n(N = 23)", "-99.7%\n(N = 19)"),
     mgp = c(3,1.5,0))
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Using cex.axis changes the size of the labels but even when the labels are quite small the spaces are still there.

Comment: Try removing the newline (`\n`) from the `labels`.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine came up with a good solution: instead of using "\n", create a second line of label just for the "(*N* = ...)" below the first line of labels, such as:

```
lab_ns <- expression(paste("(", italic(N), " = 29)"),
                 paste("(", italic(N), " = 21)"),
                 paste("(", italic(N), " = 13)"),
                 paste("(", italic(N), " = 18)"),
                 paste("(", italic(N), " = 23)"),
                 paste("(", italic(N), " = 19)"))

boxplot(pup.mass.M, font=c(3), main="males pupal mass", cex.axis=1, xlab="Diet casein content", xaxt='n' , yaxt='n', ylab="Mass (g)", ylim = c(0.22, 0.38), las = 1)

axis(1, lwd = 1, labels = c("Control", "-25%", "-50%", "-75%", "-90%", "-99.7%"), at=seq(1, 6), mgp = c(3,0.5,0))

axis(1, lwd = 0, labels = lab_ns, at=seq(1, 6), padj = 0.6)

axis(2, at=seq(0.22, 0.38, by=0.02), las = 1, mgp = c(3,1,0))
```

This displays what I am looking for. Then it's just a matter of adjusting the space between the two lines of label using "padj".